# Write special case of product multiplication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, product

I have a problem using prod (or symprod) function in Matlab when I need to bypass several indexes as the example below:

```
i = 1 to 5;
```

In this case, I do not need to use i = 2:

```
f = (1 - x(1))*(1 - x(3))*(1 - x(4))*(1 - x(5))
```

How to write this equation using 'prod' or 'symprod' in Matlab?

Comment: `prod(1-x([1 3:5]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that x represents a vector, you can use the following syntax:

```
res = prod(1-x([1,3:5]));
```

If you are using a loop, such that the variable ii represents the coordinate to omit, you can use:

```
res = prod(1-x([1:ii-1,ii+1:end]))
```

Comment: What if I do looping process to bypass x=i sequentially for each interation?

Comment: Final question, can I still use the same formula if I want to bypass x=1 and x=end?It seems weird when ii=1 or ii=end. @drorco